# Two of my partitions disappeared. I can t access these partitions from Nautilus

Tags: mount, partitioning

However GParted detects them. The filesystems were ext4 and NTFS (old Windows partition). They used to be mounted at `/media/part1` for the ext4 and `/media/ntfs`.

Last night after reading through the man pages for `mount` and `fs`, I put together this solution: create the missing directories in the `/media` directory and then type:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 ext4
```

... etc.

Is this the way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your partitions are labeled you can try with:

```
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/<partition-label>
```

which will mount your partition in `/media/<partition-label>`. For labeling partitions (which is just naming them), you can use GParted. It is nice to have labels for your partitions anyway. `udisks` if configured correctly does not prompt you for root privileges.

Another way is issuing:

```
sudo blkid
```

to get your partitions UUID, and using

```
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/<partition-uuid>
```

(This mounts the partition in `/media/<partition-label>` if the partition has a label.)

Read `man udisks` to see other features.